# Swift evaluateJavaScript not removing placeholder in search bar

Tags: javascript, swift

I'm trying to using `evalulateJavaScript` and a web view to try and search for groceries but for some reason, the search bar isn't removing the placeholder and when I click search button it says that no text has been entered. What am I doing wrong? I add a photo to show the issue.

```
fileprivate func setupWebView() {

    let url = URL(string: "https://shop.coles.com.au/a/a-national/home")!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    //Frame not required
    webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: 300, height: 300)
    webView.load(request)
    //Also not required
    view.addSubview(webView)


}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    guard let searchText = searchBar.text else { return }

    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('searchTerm').value='\(searchText)'") { (value, error) in
        self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('btnSearch').submit();", completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

[image: issue photo]

Answer (score 0):

The [website](https://shop.coles.com.au/a/a-national/home) that you've mentioned in your code is using a [P tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp) for showing a placeholder in the search bar which is why the placeholder is not getting removed when you set the value using JavaScript. You need to contact the developer of the site for a workaround.